# New page is rendering before precondition is met in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a log in page that upon successful authentication server-side will change the page using react-router. However, for some reason the new 'Contact' page is rendering before the request function has finished its task.

```
handleSubmit() {
    if (makeRequest(this.state.username, this.state.password)) {
        browserHistory.replace('Contact');
    }
}
```

Interestingly, if the login details are not valid the page wont change. I have console logs in the request function that should display if it is run, and they are not showing when valid details are entered.

If the replace is commented out the makeRequest() finishes its task properly.

I'm very new to JS and React, and am aware I must have made an error in my logic! Thank you!

Comment: would probably be good if you provided more code

Comment: What does makeRequest return? a promise or data?

Answer (score 1):

Your `makeRequest` is a asynchronous task, you should use a asynchronous tasks manage solution, suach as Promise, Generator, async await

Comment: Thanks! I've used the aync library to run each line in series. I was warned that lines in js dont run in order and i'm glad this has worked for now

Answer (score 0):

You may be making a mistake in your `makeRequest` method.
We may be able to help you if you can show us its implementation or you can provide some code similar to your `makeRequest` method.